# Custom Mobile Services API - scalibility/elasticy for huge data?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am planning to use Azure Mobile Services for the mobile app I am planning to develop. Its a bit of  social kind of app. (I am expecting a lot of data - relations and storage(pics etc. ). For the app, I wish to use Azure Mobile Services for easily adding oAuth authentication for my app, Mobile services also provide other useful features like granular control to data access, push notifications etc.

I plan to use Azure SQL for hierarchical data and Azure Storage for images etc. 
So for my data service API, writing custom API in Mobile service seem to be the natural way.

But I am bit apprehensive about developing my data service API in Mobile Services; when I think what if my data grows huge, somehow I have doubts will Mobile services API be able to handle huge data, thick and fast flying data requests.

(The size of data I am looking at is - on an average each user may add 'one' post of lets say 1000 words and 3 picture files on an average, not sure how many users, but users will be worldwide)

Does someone has any experience with performance/scalability- elasticity of Custom WepAPI? If you can kindly share your experiences/knowledge in this regard, I'll really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Azure Mobile Services does provide scaling...  This means getting into the paid services, for example: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/mobile-services/

You can also scale out the SQL database used in your mobile services.  For some detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193178.aspx

If you think even that might be an issue, I'd recommend wrapping the use of the services so you can swap them out easily.

Comment: sorry, but I didn't quite understand what does the 'wrapping the use of the services' mean? Can you pls elaborate

Comment: "Wrapping" as in use of a façade or adapter pattern implementation.